Monkeys, spores and bouncy mushrooms
I have acrobatic monkeys whose habitats are littered with massive, bouncy mushrooms. Whenever the monkeys need to quickly move or go to high places, they jump on the caps of the mushrooms, utilizing the mushrooms' bounciness.
The monkeys shift their bodies to always land on the caps with their hands or feet. They're basically doing constant backflips.
Whenever the monkeys press on the caps, the mushrooms release spores that stick to the monkeys' fur. The spores will not detach from the fur no matter how much the monkeys jump around.
When the monkeys finally stop bouncing around, they vigorously shake their fur, energetically move their bodies and wave their limbs around which somehow detach and spread the spores.
How do I justify their fur preventing the spores from dispersing during jumping but not after it?

Timed release.
The purpose of this is to spread the spores.  There's no point doing that close to the parent fungus, but with time the monkeys will move away.  After a while, the monkeys will have moved far enough to warrant detatching the spores in the hope that some will settle in a location suitable for growth.
Mushroom spores are an example of r/K selection theory that tends toward the 'r': placing an emphasis on producing a great many offspring (spores) with little investment for each in the hope that wide distribution will result in an offspring that matures to the point where it can reproduce.
So, there's no point in the fungus investing too much in ensuring that the spores will be shed at just the right place.  Just ensure a delay and hope that a few will grow.
When the monkeys bounce on the mushrooms, the impact would cause spores to be ejected, and activate the sticky compound that causes them to stick to the monkeys' fur.  The adhesive would contain an enzyme that would slowly break down the activated adhesive, so after a while - coincidentally about the time it takes for the monkeys to stop to rest - the adhesive finishes breaking down, and a simple shake of the monkey's body will set the spores loose.

I was going to comment on the r/K selection theory myself. Do what actual mushrooms do: make lots of tiny spores. You only need one in a million to get through to the right place. Every time the monkey brushes itself, some will stick, and some will detach. Any sophistication over that has to be added to every spore, increasing their 'cost' to the parent organism.

@NeilSlater: That's what i was thinking. Poppy seed come in that small capsule that opens when its dried out and releases the seeds, for example.  There's also that one plant which fruits have a  plant fiber spring inside and "explode" when dried out, catapulting its seeds quite some distance.

Grooming
Monkey troops spend a lot of time grooming each other, partly to remove parasites, and partly as a social thing. Naturally they would remove these spores as well. But they taste bad, so they don't eat them.

One could argue that eating them can be part of the seeds life cycle. Like some berries get eaten by birds, the final seeds being pooped out further away, the poop acting as a fertiliser. So either way the seeds can move great distances. The only problem with grooming that I can see is that the monkeys might have some more or less fixed points where they groom, giving an unequal distribution of seeds and high concentrations at several points. Great answer regardless.

@Trioxidane, bird digestive tracts are designed for high throughput and low efficiency -- birds need to keep their weight down in order to fly.  Monkey digestive tracts are almost the exact opposite, so it's much harder to design a seed that will survive a trip through it.

You're being too impatient.
The spores are on hair and hair sheds, so just wait a bit.
Besides that why would it be any different from goose grass burrs anyway.. they stick.. a few get rubbed off against things the animal squeezes past.. most get groomed off.. that's enough for the plant.. why wouldn't it be enough for your mushroom? your problem isn't a problem I think.
Or do you just want the monkeys to shake the spores off when you want them to because that's just what you want, but want it to make sense that they could as well? (aka 'have I fundamentally misunderstood the assignment' )

It doesn't make much sense that a jump cannot detach the spores, but a vigorous shake can: they bring similar acceleration to the body part involved.
But wiping away helps getting rid of something that a shake doesn't move. It's the same reason we wipe out sweat from our body and not just jump around to make it drip to the ground.
Even cats lick their own shed hair away, do not just jump around to lose it.
Same for your monkeys.

Change nothing
There are many strategies to reproduce. Your idea for spreading is too rigid. There's two important aspects of the seeds to consider.
The first is that there are many. Even if many dislodge themselves during the first flip, there are still plenty of seeds left. They can lose those at a later time.
The second is that only spreading far is a bad strategy. You want to spread close as well. The parent could grow there, so close by to the parent there is a high likelihood of a good environment to grow.
Not to mention that the monkeys already provide a good distance service even if the seeds dislodge in the first flip. Thanks to the spinning and lift power of the jumps they already spread pretty well. That means a good saturation in short to middle distance, while long and ultra long have less chance, but still happen regularly enough for a 'long distance' new spawn.
Just have the monkeys flip and jump around with enough seeds that have some clinging power in the fir and all should be right.

Others have pointed out you don't actually need such a mechanism, but if you want to stick with it simplest is to have spores to be sticky while fresh and humid; when they dry up they become "just powder" naturally falling from fur even without grooming.
Notice if monkeys keep jumping around sweat may keep spores moist and thus clingy; OTOH when monkey rests both it and spores dry up and grooming becomes more effective.

The monkeys pass much of their resting time grooming each other - They pluck out the fleas holding under the hairs and eat them. The spores get ingested as well. However, they are not affected by the monkey's digestive enzymes. Instead, they pass through the guts and find their way out along with the fecal matter. The spores are provided ample nutrients in the form of fecal matter. After all, they live off decaying organic matter, both plant and animal. The spores may even improve their chances of completing this part of the cycle, if the mushrooms eject some droplets which stick to the fur and harden. They resemble fleas and the monkeys would still eat them. Since monkeys are territorial, they would hang around this area protecting it. The spores would spread anywhere within their territory. Occasionally, territorial changes occur and they are dispersed into new areas.
